# Как сделать круглый Image?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как сделать круглый Image, чтобы картинка которую в него ложишь, обрезала все края которые за кругом? Если картинка большого размера, хочется чтобы она отрисовывала только центр картинки, и не отображала края. Пытаюсь сделать вот так, но такой эффект совсем не устраивает:

```
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="50,50,50,50">
            <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="image.jpg"></Image>
        </Border>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Просто берите вместо картинки `Ellipse`, а картинку положите как `Fill`. Эллипс задаст форму, а картинка — заполнение.

```
<Ellipse Width="100" Height="100">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/bg.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Результат:

[image: круглая картинка]

Comment: То что и нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!